# Why can't I send data between 2 of my computers?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, server, ip

I am working on a message format that is encrypted.

The textCoder function makes the messages nonreadable for humans and textDecoder just makes the received message readable for humans.

I have the below code for both a PC and a server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;
std::string textCoder(std::string text){....}
std::string textDecoder(std::string text){....}
int main() {
WSADATA data;
WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
int wsOk = WSAStartup(version, &data);
if (wsOk != 0) {
    std::cout << "A aparut o eroare la Winsock! " << wsOk;
    
}

SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
sockaddr_in serverHint;
serverHint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = ADDR_ANY;
std::cout << serverHint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr << endl;
serverHint.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverHint.sin_port = htons(54000);
if (bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&serverHint, sizeof(serverHint)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    std::cout << "Nu se poate bind!\n " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
}

sockaddr_in client;
ZeroMemory(&client, sizeof(client));
int clientSize = sizeof(client);

char buffer[1024];

Sleep(7000);
std::cout << "ServerStarted!!!!\n";

while (true)
{
    //Here is waiting for data to read
    ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    int bytesReceived = recvfrom(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);
    if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "A aparut o eroare " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        continue;
    }
    
    char clientIp[256];
    ZeroMemory(clientIp, sizeof(clientIp));

    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, clientIp, sizeof(clientIp));

    string messageAsString;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        messageAsString += (int)buffer[i];
    }

    //This decodes the message to a readable format
    std::cout << messageAsString << endl;
    int decoderTimes = (int)messageAsString[4] - 48;
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < decoderTimes; i++) {
        messageAsString = textDecoder(messageAsString);
    }
    std::cout << clientIp << " :" << messageAsString << endl;
    
    
}
closesocket(sock);

WSACleanup();

}
```

And the client code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>


#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;


std::string textCoder(std::string text){....}
std::string textDecoder(std::string text){....}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
WSADATA data;
WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
int wsOk = WSAStartup(version, &data);
if (wsOk != 0) {
    cout << "A aparut o eroare la Winsock! " << wsOk;

}

sockaddr_in server;
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(54000);

inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.1.7", &server.sin_addr);

SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

std::vector<int> keyPressedRow;

string s;
cin >> s;
string messageStructure;

messageStructure = "01204"+s;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    messageStructure = textCoder(messageStructure);
}
//string s(argv[1]);
int sentVerify = sendto(sock, messageStructure.c_str(), messageStructure.size() + 1, 0, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));
if (sentVerify == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    cout << "Eroare la mesaj! \n" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;

}

closesocket(sock);

WSACleanup();
}
```

The "01204" is added to the message just because it contains info like who is this message for, the id of client, how much times the message needs to get in textDecoder function etc.

The client sends the message to the server running on private IP address 192.168.1.7 and the client runs on 192.168.1.5.

However, the server does not receive any message! Is something wrong with the code and/or network configuration?

Comment: Possible firewall

Comment: Personnaly I use `serverHint.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);` on the server side. Maybe do the difference. Or firewall on your router

Comment: And on the client side I'm using `server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.7");`

Comment: @MaximeCharrière `INADDR_ANY` (0.0.0.0) has a numeric value of 0, so it doesn't matter if you use `htonl()` or not.